# Make relative shortcut to relative target

Tags: batch-file, path, shortcut, target

i have a problem that i've not found the solution after 1 hour of search on the net !

Situation :
I have a directory `\DIR`
In this directory I have a `SCRIPT.lnk` that I would like targeting `\DIR\Dependences\SCRIPT.bat`
but the `\DIR` folder will be portable (in an usb key or any other  random directory).

Have you a solution to make them relatives ? 
I've tried multiple syntax type but, none works.

Comment: Please share your attempts (add them to the question by editing your post)! Anyway, I don't think this is possible with `*.lnk` shortcuts; [tag:batch-file] is perhaps also not the best choice for creating such links...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is easy once you realize that batch files aren't executable.  It's `cmd.exe` that executes, which then interprets your batch script.  With that in mind, you can point your shortcut to `cmd.exe` in either its absolute fully-qualified path or as its traditional environment variable `%comspec%` (or `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` if you prefer).

And now, since your bat file is no longer the *target* but is now an *argument*, you can make that relative all day long.  Beauty is that if the shortcut is moved along with the folder containing the batch script to a different drive and a different depth, it'll still work.

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set "shortcutname=script.lnk"
set "shortcuttarget=DIR\Dependences\SCRIPT.bat"

powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
goto :EOF

: end batch / begin PowerShell hybrid code #>

$shortcut = (new-object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut($env:shortcutname)
$shortcut.TargetPath = "%comspec%"
$shortcut.Arguments = '/c "{0}"' -f $env:shortcuttarget
$shortcut.Save()
```

And for anyone curious as to how this can be applied to shortcuts pointing to something other than a .bat script (such as a PDF document, for example), just replace the `$shortcut.Arguments` line with this:

```js
$shortcut.Arguments = '/c start "" "{0}"' -f $env:shortcuttarget
```

Comment: okay man, thank you, but, i would like to knwo where am i supposed to write down the script you gave me ?

Comment: Oh, it's okay, i've just unbderstand that i hahe to make an batch with only this code and it makes me a  new shortcut. Thank's a lot man !

Comment: But I still have a problem, this works perfectly but if i tick "run as admin" in my bat shortcut, the bat file will not launch... any solution for this ? :)

Comment: @Thomas. it's probably because running cmd as administrator defaults the current working directory to c:\Windows\system32.  You might try setting the Working Directory to `.` or insert `$shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "."` just before `$shortcut.Save()`, but I don't know whether that'll work or not.

Comment: Thank's, I've tried, but, yeah, semms not working, the `.bat` window open up and close immediately

Comment: @Thomas. rather than specifying in the shortcut to run it as admin, try [adding some code to the top of the script](https://sites.google.com/site/eneerge/scripts/batchgotadmin) to request elevation.

Comment: Yeah, i've already found a script like this one, and it works (but not the one you've linked me btw :/) but it launches an other cmd box with my batch content, and i've used to make an shortcut because of the options that are in the shortcut (colors ,sizes etc).